# Terraform Google provider, create log-based alerting policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-monitoring

I need to create a log-based alerting policy via Terraform Google cloud provider :
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/monitoring-logs#lba

I checked from the Terraform official documentation and i saw 'google_monitoring_alert_policy' resource : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_alert_policy

I don't found with this doc how creating a log based alerting policy.
I can create an alerting policy with type 'Metrics' but not with type 'Logs'

[image]

I use the latest version of Terraform Google cloud provider : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest

How can i create a log-based alerting policy with Terraform Google provider please ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is an open issue in the Terraform provider to support conditionMatchedLog block https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/9893

Comment: Thanks for this info Diego :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks Guillaume.

Yes it's the way i solved the issue.

Now there is no way to directly create alerting with `log` type, via Terraform.

The steps to solve this problem :

- Create un log based metric with expected filter
- Create an alerting policy with type `metric` based on the previous created log based metric

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "my_log_metrics" {
  project = var.project_id
  name = "my-log-metric"
  filter = "..."
  description = "..."
  metric_descriptor {
    metric_kind = "..."
    value_type = "..."
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "my_policy" {
  project = var.project_id
  display_name = "my-policy"
  combiner = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "my-policy"
    condition_threshold {
      filter = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/my-log-metric\" AND resource.type=\"cloud_composer_environment\""
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mazlum, What value did you set for metric_kind and value_type?

Comment: Hi Richard, for example in my cases, i want to increment the metric and send an alert everytime the pattern occurs in cloud logging.

In this case, you can set the following params : 

"metric_kind": "DELTA",
"value_type": "INT64",

Comment: Hi Mazlum, many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Problem is solved with version 4.7.0 of google provider, which adds **condition_matched_log**. Here is a working example :

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "email-me" {
  display_name = "Email Me"
  type = "email"
  labels = {
    email_address = "me@mycompany.com"
  }
  
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "workflows" {
  display_name = "Workflows alert policy"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "Error condition"
    condition_matched_log {
      filter = "resource.type=\"workflows.googleapis.com/Workflow\" severity=ERROR"
    }
  }

  notification_channels = [ google_monitoring_notification_channel.email-me.name ]
  alert_strategy {
    notification_rate_limit {
      period = "300s"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible, to add a trigger to it? For example, only if within 60 Min, the condition is reached for 4 times, only then will the alert be triggered?

Comment: In this case you're better off using metrics and trigger values, as shown in the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The format is `logging.googleapis.com/user/<user metrics name>`

Look at this example (no notification, only the alert policy)

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "alert_policy" {
  display_name = "My Alert Policy"
  combiner     = "OR"
  conditions {
    display_name = "test condition"
    condition_threshold {
      filter     = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/test-metrics\" AND resource.type=\"cloud_run_revision\""
      duration   = "600s"
      comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 1
      }
    }

  user_labels = {
    foo = "bar"
  }
}
```