# How to configure an alerting policy for failed Dataproc Batch?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, dataproc, gcp-alerts

I want to alert on failure of any serverless dataproc job. I think that I may need to create a log based metric and then an alerting policy based on that metric.

I tried creating an alerting policy with the filter below:

```
      filter = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/log_entry_count\" resource.type=\"cloud_dataproc_batch\" metric.label.\"severity\"=\"ERROR\""
```

I was expecting an alert to trigger upon failure, but this metric does not seem to be active.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a dataproc jobs standard procedure and custom procedure, and I followed this
public documentation [Run an Apache Spark batch workload](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/quickstarts/spark-batch#submit_a_spark_batch_workload)

From the step, while creating dataproc job. Try to change the value of the Arguments to 0, instead to 1000. to received an a ERROR to cloud logging.

From Cloud Logging I tried to use this filter below:

```
resource.type="audited_resource"
resource.labels.method="google.cloud.dataproc.v1.BatchController.CreateBatch"
resource.labels.service="dataproc.googleapis.com"
severity = "ERROR"
```

and successfully filter the audited_resource details from Cloud Logging with severity: "ERROR"

```
{
insertId: "efuxrvd7fs2"
logName: "projects/t**h-********ra-350512/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
operation: {3}
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
authenticationInfo: {2}
methodName: "google.cloud.dataproc.v1.BatchController.CreateBatch"
requestMetadata: {2}
resourceName: "projects/t**h-********ra-350512/locations/us-central1/batches/batch-4e0c"
serviceName: "dataproc.googleapis.com"
status: {2}}
receiveTimestamp: "2022-11-14T23:11:31.514920377Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2022-11-14T23:11:31.488430Z"
}
```

And also try to remove the "severity = ERROR" code to check severity: "NOTICE" in the Cloud logging

```
resource.type="audited_resource"
resource.labels.method="google.cloud.dataproc.v1.BatchController.CreateBatch"
resource.labels.service="dataproc.googleapis.com"
```

Example Output:

```
{
insertId: "-1xjqtwdo1kq"
logName: "projects/t**h-*******rra-350512/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
operation: {3}
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
authenticationInfo: {2}
authorizationInfo: [1]
methodName: "google.cloud.dataproc.v1.BatchController.CreateBatch"
request: {4}
requestMetadata: {4}
resourceLocation: {1}
resourceName: "projects/t**h-j*******a-350512/locations/us-central1/batches/batch-4e0c"
serviceName: "dataproc.googleapis.com"
status: {0}}
receiveTimestamp: "2022-11-14T23:06:27.771245352Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "NOTICE"
timestamp: "2022-11-14T23:06:26.339799Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `log based metric` that filters your `Dataproc` jobs errors, then create an alerting policy on this `log based metric`, example with `Terraform` :

[alerting policy log based metric terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033535/9261558)

For your `log based metric`, you have to add your filter, example :

```
"filter": "resource.type=\"cloud_dataproc_cluster\" AND severity=ERROR AND jsonPayload.message =~ \"mytext.*\"",
```